# Spring-Security Как получить авторизованного пользователя

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, j2ee

Всем привет! Как можно получить авторизованного пользователя, т.е после авторизации извлечь обьект данного юзера из БД к примеру для того чтобы заполнить поля на его странице профиля, DAO у меня реализован с помощью hibernate и сама авторизация выполняется из БД. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для этого сначала нужно получить имя юзера из spring-security

```
public String getCurrentUsername() {
      Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      return auth.getName();
  }
```

и передать его в hibernate

```
public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
    CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> userRequest = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);

    Expression<String> exp = userRequest.get("username");
    Predicate predicate = exp.in(username);

    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);
    try {
        return em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, важная особенность, как отметил @Nofate, спринговый user и объект из бд - это разные сущности

Answer (score 8):

Начиная с Spring-Security 3.2 удобнее воспользоваться аннотацией [@AuthenticationPrincipal](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/bind/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipal.html) на аргументе метода вашего контроллера.

```
ModelAndView someRequestHandler(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    // ...
}
```

`User` - это именно спринговый юзер, а не тот объект, который вы кладете в БД.

Чтобы это работало, нужно зарегистрировать бин `AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver`:

- при использовании Java-конфигурации - повесть аннотацию `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` на ваш `@Configuration`-бин;
- при использовании xml-конфигурации - зарегистрировать его в `<mvc:argument-resolvers>`:

  ```xml
  <mvc:annotation-driven>
       <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver"/>         
       </mvc:argument-resolvers>
  </mvc:annotation-driven>
  ```